Facing an issue to run an iOS Application from Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile application
I am trying to run a sample application created from a Kotlin Multiplatform template, I did not change anything. It is running for Android but not for iOS. I try to check by creating sample application only for iOS from Xcode which is working fine. I am using Xcode 15.4 and my mac os is Sonoma Version 14.6.1
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'TestKMP'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.5.2
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.5.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')

* Try:
> Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
> No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Configuration cache entry stored.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Volumes/Macintosh_HD_Data/KMP/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Script-7555FFB5242A651A00829871.sh (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
(1 failure)
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')

Below is the kdoctor result:


Check your build.gradle.kts file under shared or composeApp.
Chances are, you've added the following Android-only dependency to your iosMain dependencies:
iosMain.dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.2") // just remove this
}

Option 2: Get a better template.
Additional Note: Don't do Gradle or AGP updates that pop up on the bottom right hand of your screen until after you successfully build for the first time.  I've dealt with a lot of those updates breaking KMP templates unexpectedly.
